# orthogonal matrix proiection on a space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q is the matrix:

$ 1/2
  \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

I have to find the orthogonal projection matrix on the space $N (Q^T) $.

I found that a basis for $N (Q^T) $ is ${(0,0,1,-1), (1,-1,0,0)}$.

How can I conclude ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Find two vectors that span the orthogonal of $N(Q^T)$. Then the projector $p$ you're looking for is vanishing for those two vectors and the image of the vectors you found is themselves.

With this you have defined $p$ on a basis, hence on the space.